# Decrypting WPA2 WLAN traffic in Wireshark

Tags: encryption, wireshark, pcap, network-traffic, wifi

I have trouble decrypting WPA2 WLAN traffic in Wireshark.

I've done research and followed all advises I could possibly find and still cannot decrypt it. There are of course plenty of variables, but I strongly believe I covered all of them, and yet I'm still missing out something.

Basically, all I can view is Probs, Beacons, Null function (No data) and QoS Null function (No data). I connect to the network with my phone and start randomly browsing and can clearly see my traffic is going in Wireshark, but it only Null function (No data) packets.

I've made sure I added [password]:[ssid] to 802.11 and enabled decryption. Always have long streams and full EAPOLs when capturing the traffic and tried on three different wifi cards (Alfa, TP-link & Intel). I have most up to Kali distribution and latest Wireshark version, and tried on someone else pcaps and Wireshark decrypted it successfully.

The only thing I can think of causing this is the driver.

Comment: Hi, please go through [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . You should post all the things you tried, maybe along with screenshots.

Comment: The question is off-topic anyway, since it is not a programming question.

Comment: What version of Wireshark are you using, and on what platform?  It can often be very helpful to provide Wireshark's "Help -> About Wireshark" information when reporting problems.

Anyway, if you're not running the very latest version, you could try upgrading it to see if there might have been any bug fixes affecting you.  You might even try one of the latest automated builds from https://www.wireshark.org/download/automated/.

And in case you haven't visited these sites yet, see also https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN and https://wiki.wireshark.org/Wi-Fi.

Comment: Which key type did you select? For the human-set passphrase, "wpa-pwd" is required.